# How to embed user reposes in Bot replies in gushup whatsapp bot

Tags: whatsapp, gupshup

I am trying to create a whatsapp business chat bot using gupshup Flow bot builder but not able to find any documentation related to include the user responses in the nest follow up message. For example:
Bot says: Please tell me your name
User: John
Bot says: welcome John.

Now this bot reply should include the last response as a variable because username would be different for each user.